# kal calender change mark event color

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode

I use Klazuka/Kal controller for selection dates.when I add events from two different arrays.so

basically I have two array in which there is different dates. so,I want to distinguish these two

arrays dates when they show as an event in calender.

Please suggest some way to get out of this.Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CGColor is a property of a EKCalendar. There is no property of EKEvents to set color to it. All the events in a particular calendar would have the same color.

You can create different calendar for the color differentiation

```
    EKEventStore *eventStore = [[EKEventStore alloc] init];

    EKCalendar *calendar = [EKCalendar calendarWithEventStore:eventStore];
    calendar.title = calendarName; // set calendar name
    calendar.CGColor = [UIColor grayColor].CGColor // set whichever color you want here

    bool success= [eventStore saveCalendar:calendar commit:YES error:&error];
```

Refer [this](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/DataManagement/Reference/EKCalendarClassRef/Reference/Reference.html)

Comment: gray not supported in my case. but red,yellow,and others are supported.very strange.